# Stacked bar chart from grouped pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: ID, date, and priority:

```
ID  date   priority
1   2007   High
2   2007   Low
3   2010   Medium
4   2007   High
```

This is 12,000 rows in length. Every ID (person) is unique and has a date and priority assigned

what I want to do is plot a bar chart with Year on the x axis and the height being the total number of people (ID's) but it needs to be stacked by priority. 
So suppose I have 10 Ids in 2007 (5 from medium, 3 low, and 2 high) I need to plot 2007 with height 10 stacked accordingly.

This is what I am trying:

```
total = data.groupby(['date']).priority.value_counts()
```

This gives me the head of the pandas series:

```
date       priority
2000        High               6
            Medium             5
            Low                4
2001        High               6
            Medium             2
2002        High               1
            Medium             3
            Low                4
2003        High              10
            Medium             3
```

How do I plot date on x axis and the total of numbers on height broken down by H,M,L.

Comment: Please can you share a sample of your dataframe

Comment: how about `total.plot.bar(stacked=True)`?

Comment: Hi b-fg. I tried that but didn't work

Comment: Hi nixon. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check with `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.date,df.priority).plot(kin='bar')
```

Comment: I tried your code and also tried it with stacked=True: pd.crosstab(df.Start_Date,df.Giving_Segment).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True) but I get loads of black lines on x axis. The thing is the dataframe is 11,549 rows with repeated dates between 2000 - 2017

Comment: @user8322222 blank means count zero

Comment: Worked! Thanks!! :)

Comment: I get the cross tab as H-L-M but I want L-M-H. would you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: @user8322222 adding reindex `pd.crosstab(df.date,df.priority).reindex(columns=['Low','Medium','High']).plot(kin='bar')`

Comment: Thanks W-B. That worked great. I have another question on a similar data-frame but since this specific question is answered I asked it separately. Would love your thoughts on it if you get the chance as it's very similar to this question except it's dealing with sum of money rather than an individual.  
                  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525292/stacked-bar-chart-for-grouped-pandas-series

Comment: @user8322222 add the solution